# Mac OS X & SVN - Handling accented filenames

Tags: macos, maven, svn

I have a setup with Intellij Idea, Maven 3 and SVN 1.7 on Yosemite.

Everything works fine until I try to deploy a project with accented filenames.

The files were created on a Windows machine, and when I do the checkout on the Mac, the files are fine, but SVN sees them as not under version control:

```
$ svn st --verbose
              4319      608 llozes       contract
              4319      608 llozes       contract/design
?                                        contract/design/Dise~no - Carga Contratos.xlsx
?                                        contract/design/Dise~no - Nueva Cabecera.xlsx
!             4319      331 llozes       contract/design/Diseño - Carga Contratos.xlsx
!             4319      608 llozes       contract/design/Diseño - Nueva Cabecera.xlsx
```

The two original files are

- Diseño - Carga Contratos.xlsx
- Diseño - Nueva Cabecera.xlsx

It seems that SVN changes the name in their properties (Dise~no), but in the filesystem, the filenames are correct.

When I try to deploy with Maven, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project wdCell-parent: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
[ERROR] [analisis/contract/design/Dise~no - Carga Contratos.xlsx:unknown]
[ERROR] [analisis/contract/design/Dise~no - Nueva Cabecera.xlsx:unknown]
[ERROR] [analisis/contract/design/Diseño - Carga Contratos.xlsx:missing]
[ERROR] [analisis/contract/design/Diseño - Nueva Cabecera.xlsx:missing]
```

It seems to be an encoding problem, but I don't find any solutions online (from what I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/svnx/issues/detail?id=156) for example, it seems there's no fix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's down to the difference in filing systems (specifically types of UTF-8) between Windows and Linux and OSX: https://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/401/0/problems-with-umlauts--in-filenames-on-mac-os-x

As far as we're aware it's due to be fixed in Subversion 1.9 or 1.10 but as yet there's no way around this except to use Windows or Linux to check these files out.

Comment: This link is obsolete.